# Databricks (Create group (workspace local-group) under admin setting)

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, databricks

I wanted create group and add user in Databricks under admin setting but, my query is to do if the group exist/already created add user under the group, " CREATE GROUP IF NOT EXISTS group_name; " is not working.

```
IF NOT EXISTS [SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'group_name' AND type = 'X']
BEGIN
CREATE GROUP group_name;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
ALTER GROUP group_name ADD USER `user@g.com`;
END
```

then I hv try this query as well its not working too.

```
BEGIN TRY
CREATE groups group_name;
END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH
ALTER GROUP group_name ADD USER `user@g.com`;
END CATCH
```

Please help me on this with Python or SQL coding